# How to override function getAdditionalData() of block Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes.php file

Tags: magento2, overrides

How to override `function getAdditionalData()` of `Attributes.php` file in magento 2.

`di.xml` file code,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" type="Test\Details\Block\Attribute"/>
</config>
```

Block file code,

```
<?php
namespace Test\Details\Block;


class Attribute extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes
{

    public function getAdditionalData(array $excludeAttr = [])
    {
        $data = [];
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {
                $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

                if (!$product->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
                    $value = __('N/A');
                } elseif ((string)$value == '') {
                    $value = __('No');
                } elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price' && is_string($value)) {
                    $value = $this->priceCurrency->convertAndFormat($value);
                }

//i have to remove if condtion from this function here....
                    $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = [
                        'label' => __($attribute->getStoreLabel()),
                        'value' => $value,
                        'code' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
                    ];
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }    
}
```

After override block, Main information tab is remove automatically,
I have to work in main information tab of product detail page.

i have checked log file and log error are display like this,

```
main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'product/view/attributes.phtml' in module: 'Test_Details' block's name: 'product.attributes' [] [].
```

Any suggestion for issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 2 uses the current module to get a template path. When overriding a block in this way but still want it to use the template from the original module you have to add a _toHtml function to your block to reset the module name like so...

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes'));
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

I found this from another thread that i cannot locate at the moment. If i do i will add the link.