# Magento 2: How to override Product View Attributes block?

Tags: magento2, layout, template, overrides

How to **override Product View Attributes block**:

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php` in Magento 2?

Jsp/Attributes/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Jsp_Attributes" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Jsp/Attributes/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes"
                type="Jsp\Attributes\Block\Product\View\Attributes" />
</config>
```

Jsp/Attributes/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
  \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
  'Jsp_Attributes',
  __DIR__
);
```

Jsp/Attributes/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php

```
<?php

namespace Jsp\Attributes\Block\Product\View;

class Attributes extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes
{
    public function getAdditionalData(array $excludeAttr = ['colorprueba'])
    {
        $data = [];
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {
                $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

                if (!$product->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
                    $value = __('N/A');
                } elseif ((string)$value == '') {
                    $value = __('No');
                } elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price' && is_string($value)) {
                    $value = $this->priceCurrency->convertAndFormat($value);
                }

                if (is_string($value) && strlen($value)) {
                    $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = [
                        'label' => __($attribute->getStoreLabel()),
                        'value' => $value,
                        'code' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about your issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2: How to move additional product attributes to Details tab?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120725/magento-2-how-to-move-additional-product-attributes-to-details-tab)

Comment: Do what Khoa did and also look here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98160/how-to-override-function-getadditionaldata-of-block-magento-catalog-block-prod

Answer (score 1):

In your custom module:

*app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes"
                type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Attributes" />
</config>
```

*app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php*

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View;

class Attributes extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes
{
    //Override here...
}
```

Remember to add the sequence module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: This is working solution, but some problems: 1. use scope-specific di.xml (frontend/di.xml) 2. preference does not good idea for reliable extension.

Comment: @MaxStsepantsevich 1) I'm not test yet, but I agree. May need to test later 2) we will use Plugin or any idea?

Comment: 2. Yes, i think that using plugins or layout modification are better solutions :)

Comment: I tried your code, however now the "More Information" tab dissappears from product pages

Comment: @LuisGarcia I update my answer. Remember to add the sequence module.

Comment: The "More Information" tab is still missing from product page. I updated my question to include the code I created for my module

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: Hmmm, try to add the constructor function in the custom class.

Comment: My Magento version is 2.1.0